# Special search of span not containing another span

Tags: jquery

I need to select all span elements which: 1) do not contain other span elements and 2) contain the text 123 as inner text (on their own level).

How do I do this?

Comment: @tlindell Many things but neither works or look too clumsy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this selector:

```
$('span:contains(123):not(:has(span))')
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/b8axzjva/

Comment: Wow, didn't know we can use :not and :has on the same time !

Comment: @Arthur Yes, the whole expression sounds like a natural language :)

Comment: The only additional thing to this is it will find spans inside spans with the text '123'. Or in other words, it will (possibly erroneously) find elements with this structure: `<span><span>123</span></span>`. That might be for OP to worry about.

Comment: @filoxo Yes, I know. However this requirement `contain the text 123 as inner text` can be ambiguous. So let's see what OP thinks.

Comment: Well, I don't need those <span><span>123</span></span>. I need only leaf-level spans which contain 123, basically. So when I find such a structure, I want just the inner span.

Comment: I think your original solutions works fine for me though. Not sure I got the counter example of filoxo.

Comment: dfsq: Agreed, +1 regardless of ambiguity :) @peter.petrov Perhaps, this modified version of dsfq's fiddle might illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/b8axzjva/1/. Notice that on the fifth example, the text '123' is also highlighted red. So your requirement might change so that it *excludes* sublevel spans with the text '123'.

Comment: Yes, solution in this case would be less elegant.

Comment: @filoxo Well, I want the 5th one highlighted red because it does not contain another span inside itself, and contains the text 123 as its own inner text (the inner span, I mean). Anyway, thank you both!

Comment: More flexible solution would be something like Arthur demonstrated, with `each` and manual node contents checking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it on only one query (@dfsq show us about yes you can).

But look with a .each function, something like that :

```
$('span').each(function(){
  if(! $(this).find('span') && $(this).text() === "123"){
    // Is good
  }
});
```